# Why are files moving to 'backup' in storage when I delete them off my macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, external-disk, storage

Back in the summer I bought an external hard drive for my MacBook Pro because I make videos on YouTube and they obviously take up a **lot** of space on my computer. The first couple of times I plugged the new drive in, moved the videos/files to it and deleted them from my computer I got a **tonne** of storage space back (as of course was expected).

But recently, when I went to move more videos to clear up space, I didn’t get the amount of space I expected back. In fact, the space I got back from deleting movies went into the “backup” part of my storage and the same goes for random files. **Why** is this happening? I don’t use Time Machine or anything. How can I prevent this from happening because it’s driving me nuts and limiting my current movie imports.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! To help people help you, you should provide as many details on your problem while striving to keep your question concise. In this case, you might want to explain what you mean by the “backup part” of your storage (this last one being your internal HD, I suppose?), what “random files” you find there, and what “or anything” you are not using.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to disable local time machine backups by the sound of it.

```
 sudo tmutil disablelocal
```

Or you can just ignore that space that's allocated as backups and once the drive fills to 80%, the system automatically prunes old backups.

Comment: It actually seems to have fixed itself, strangely enough. it dropped from 121GB to 12... and it did that before I started to clean out other useless crap from my laptop. But how would I go about disabling local time machine? :)

Comment: [Here's a page full of info about local snapshots](http://pondini.org/TM/30.html). But seriously, you don't need to disable it. They surrender their space automatically. I don't know why the Storage page doesn't make this more explicit. The amount shown in Finder does exclude them, though - that's the Free number you should pay attention to.

Answer (score 0):

Open System Preferences, under the Apple Menu, and the Time Machine preference pane.

Turn it to Off.